# Ошибка при получении данных из Firebase при работе с Retrofit

Tags: android, firebase, retrofit

Есть код:

```
public interface Api {
    @GET("data/")
    Call<List<Model>> galleryContent();

   /* @GET("posts/")
    Call<List<Model>> galleryContent();*/ //Фейковый апи
}

public class ApiClient {
    public static final String BASE_URL = "https://*****.firebaseio.com/";
    //public static final String BASE_URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/"; //Фейковый апи
    private static Retrofit retrofit;

    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        if (retrofit == null) {

            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}

public class Model {
    public String id;
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String title;
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
}

public class QRActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_qr);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        Api api = ApiClient.getClient().create(Api.class);
        Call<List<Model>> gallery = api.galleryContent();
        gallery.enqueue(new Callback<List<Model>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Model>> call, Response<List<Model>> response) {
                if (response.body() != null && response.isSuccessful()) {
                    List<Model> models = response.body();
                    Model model = models.get(0);
                    textView.append(model.getId() + "\n\n");
                    textView.append(model.getTitle() + "\n\n");

                } else{
                        textView.append("" + response.code());
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Model>> call, Throwable t) {
                textView.append("" + t);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Вот скрин АПИ из Firebase:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот скрин экран эмулятора:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я понимаю, что проблема в структуре БД в Firebase, как правильно его оформить?

Comment: Почему именно в структуре БД? Вам приходит некорректный JSON, возможно вообще не JSON. Прочтите ответ как строку и посмотрите что там, или Retrofit interceptor повесьте и будет вам подсказка.

Comment: а зачем Retrofit для Firebase? там все методы получения данных асинхронные. попробуйте без ретрофита получить данные